# Line colour of ggplot looks very weird when plotting a large number of data points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a line with ggplot, however the colour of the line looks very weird. At some points it looks much thicker than at other points. Is this maybe because I have too many data points? How can this be solved?
I only have this problem with large datasets, the data for the plot in this example can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vStSiQKRC8wac8vVj4qBtgf6yfzR6grtNWCfZx1fCpzCjXRlzvX1yLhLUNPhB41F5uHlmcY8HseIM5y/pub?output=csv)

```
ggplot(data=largedataframe, aes(x=Time, y=Value)) +
  geom_line(size=2, aes(colour='T1'))
```

[image: example]

Comment: Please edit the question to include enough data to reproduce your problem. Use `dput` to make the data easily imported.

Comment: @Hanna the google doc link failed to load.

Comment: I should work now, sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: I am unable to reproduce on my machine, mine looks [like this](https://imgur.com/a/GxxNQ). Are you running the latest version of ggplot2?

Comment: That is interesting... I do run the latest version of ggplot (2.2.1)

Answer (score 0):

Like Michael Bird, I got a plot that looks all right. There appears to be a slight "bloat" to the line's thickness at some places (one example circled below), but I wouldn't have noticed it if I wasn't looking for it:

[image: full view]

Zooming all the way in until the individual data points become distinct gives a clearer view:

```
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Time, y = Value)) +
  geom_point(color = "salmon", size = 1) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1000000, 1300000),
                  ylim = c(0.75, 0.8))

p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Time, y = Value)) +
  geom_point(color = "salmon", size = 1) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1180000, 1220000),
                  ylim = c(0.76, 0.79))

p3 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Time, y = Value)) +
  geom_point(color = "salmon", size = 0.1) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1207000, 1211000),
                  ylim = c(0.769, 0.774))

p4 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Time, y = Value)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(color = "salmon", size = 1) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1207700, 1208000),
                  ylim = c(0.7695, 0.7705))

gridExtra::grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, nrow = 2)
```

[image: zoom-in view]

There *are* points where the y value zig-zags slightly, which would account for a slightly thicker line at those points.

Personally I don't think it's a major problem, but if you're looking for an explanation why some line segments look thicker, this could account for it.

Comment: Thanks! I've 'solved' the issue by plotting points instead of a line...